# Magento: How do I get the selected value from a group of radio buttons from a custom option?

Tags: magento, prototypejs

I have a custom option, which holds 2 options. There is no button group or something created by Magento, the radio buttons and the labels are in a < ul >, so how would I get the selected radio button? This is the code:

```
<ul id="options-22-list" class="options-list">
    <li>
        <input id="options_22_2" class="radio validate-one-required-by-name product-  custom-option" type="radio" price="6.8" value="40" name="options[22]" onclick="opConfig.reloadPrice()">
        <span class="label">
            <label for="options_22_2">
                option1 
                <span class="price-notice">
                    +
                    <span class="price">€6.80</span>
                    </span>
             </label>
            </span>
    </li>
    <li>
        same as above just with the other option and other ids
    </li>
</ul>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I guess it should be in some form.

In PrototypeJS, you can get the selected radio button value by:

```
var radioValue = Form.getInputs('myform','radio','options[22]').find(function(radio) { 
    return radio.checked; 
}).value;
```